# Using a Regex to Replace Text Across Multiple Lines

Tags: css, regex, eclipse, gwt

I have some css files in a gwt project that need to be updated. I need to figure out a regex expression that I can use to locate and replace template expressions ('%sometext%') while also appending some prefix text based on the template before each block. For example lets say I have a chunk of css like the following:

```
.x-tabs-wrap, .x-layout-panel .x-tabs-top .x-tabs-wrap {
    background: #deecfd;
    border: 1px solid #8db2e3;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.x-tabs-strip-wrap{
    padding-top: 1px;
    background: url('%aerotabStripBggif%') #cedff5 repeat-x bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8db2e3;
}

.x-tabs-strip .x-tabs-text {
    color: #15428b;
    font: bold 11px tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif;
}

.x-tabs-strip .on .x-tabs-text {
    cursor: default;
    color: #15428b;
}

.x-tabs-top .x-tabs-strip .on .x-tabs-right {
    background: url('%aerotabSpritegif%') no-repeat right 0;
}
```

The regex should match the second and fifth blocks and capture

1. The whole block from the dot to the closing brace
2. The opening template text **url('%**
3. The template string **aerotabSpritegif**
4. The closing template text **%')**

So the final expected result would be:

```
.x-tabs-wrap, .x-layout-panel .x-tabs-top .x-tabs-wrap {
    background: #deecfd;
    border: 1px solid #8db2e3;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 0;
}

@url aerotabStripBggif aerotabStripBggif;
.x-tabs-strip-wrap{
    padding-top: 1px;
    background: aerotabStripBggif #cedff5 repeat-x bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8db2e3;
}

.x-tabs-strip .x-tabs-text {
    color: #15428b;
    font: bold 11px tahoma,arial,verdana,sans-serif;
}

.x-tabs-strip .on .x-tabs-text {
    cursor: default;
    color: #15428b;
}

@url aerotabSpritegif aerotabSpritegif;
.x-tabs-top .x-tabs-strip .on .x-tabs-right {
    background: aerotabSpritegif no-repeat right 0;
}
```

I have tried multiple different approaches and so far I can't find anything that matches correctly. Everything is either too narrow and matches nothing or too wide and ends up matching across multiple blocks. The best I have been able to come up with so far is:

```
(?s)^\.[A-Za-z]+?.+?url\(\'\%.+?\%\'\).+?\}
```

Looking at the tools on regex101 I can see that no match for url is found in the first block of text, so the matcher keeps going until it eventually finds a match in the second block. I need to somehow define that the opening dot and the closing brace are boundaries but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do to get this regex to behave as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the search pattern:

```
(?m)^(\.[^}]+?)url\('%(.+?)%'\)([^}]+})
```

and the replacement:

```
@url $2 $2;\n$1$2$3
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1S32De/1)

- The multiline mode `(?m)` makes the caret `^` match the start of any line.
- As you have found, the regex `.+?url` tries to match across blocks
  even though you have put the `?` to disable the `greedy match`.
  This is because the dot `.` matches anything regardless of the boundary.
  I have then modified it to `[^}]+?url` not to go far beyond the block.

Comment: From what I can tell, the multi-line modifier is not needed. The negation was exactly what I was looking for though. Thank you!